# How can I cache mysql connection in Flask

Tags: mysql, flask

I am using `Flask` app. Here is an api that selects data from mysql and return data to client.

In every request, I connect mysql.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xx', password='xx',
                              host='xx',
                              database='xx')
```

In my opinion, the connection takes time. So how can I use this cache? Because it seems unnecessary to connect mysql database every time.

Comment: Search for "connection pool".

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What code ?@Colin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a mysql connection pool or any better way to initialize the multiple databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658679/how-to-create-a-mysql-connection-pool-or-any-better-way-to-initialize-the-multip)